# vb.net and sql query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am new to vb.net  so bear with me. I have some managable tables in ms access database. I am trying to write a sql query that will give me following output:

```
table1 ( columnA - columnB)
table2 ( columnA - columnB)
table3 ( columnA - columnB)
```

I have column name "column A" and “column B" in all tables.

I want to retrieve tables name and sum of (column A – column B) of all tables. When I run the sql statement I get the following error:

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

Can someone help me to write a sql query please?

Here is my full code:

```vb
Dim con As New OleDbConnection(" Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\msacc.accdb")   

Dim Query2 As String = " SELECT Table1 AS Table, SUM(a) - SUM(b) AS Result FROM table1 UNION  SELECT Table2, SUM(a) - SUM(b) FROM table2  UNION SELECT Table3, SUM(a) - SUM(b) FROM table3"
Dim Da As OleDbDataAdapter, Ds As New DataSet, Dtb As New System.Data.DataTable
con.Open()
Da = New OleDbDataAdapter(Query2, con)
Da.Fill(Ds)
con.Close()
Dtb = Ds.Tables(0)
DataGridView1.DataSource = Dtb
```

Answer (score 4):

If understand correctly you're probably looking for this

1. Use quotes around string literals (`'Table1'`, `Table2`, `'Table3'`)
2. Use brackets `[]` around an alias that is a reserved word (`[Table]`)
3. Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` since you don't need to eliminate any duplicates in your resultset

```sql
SELECT 'Table1' AS [Table], SUM(a) - SUM(b) AS Result 
  FROM table1 
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table2', SUM(a) - SUM(b) 
  FROM table2  
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table3', SUM(a) - SUM(b) 
  FROM table3
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea156/1)** demo (SQL Server) *The query itself will work in MS Access just fine*

Comment: Anyway, the error he is saying is probably because of the use of `Table` as a name being a reserved word. You should use it as  @Dinup said: `[Table]`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Table1 AS **Table**

The word `Table` is a reserved word so used other name.

And `SUM()` is an aggregate function wherein you need to use a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: You only need a GROUP BY if you are grouping by another field.

Comment: @CraigT I was thinking initially that the 'Table1' he was using is a field which warrants a GROUP BY until I realized he's using a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

You have done mistake in this Query2. Dont use `SELECT Table1 AS Table` instead of this use  `select 'Table1' as [table]`